# I want to include validation on certain fields. The validation should show messages only when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs

I want to include validation on certain fields. The validation should show messages only when a checkbox is checked. I am trying to achieve this in Angular

form.cshtml

```
<input type ="checkbox" ng-click = "mainControl.reportUpdates()">
<input type = "text" date-validator = "type.date">
<ul messages = "mainform['date'+$index].$error">
   <li ng-message="required"> Required</li>
   <li ng-message = "maxdatevalidator">Date cannot be greater than today 
   </li>
<ul>
```

App.js

```
_module.directive('dateValidator', ['$rootScope','$parse',function($rootscope,$parse)])
{
  function maxDate(date)
   {
      var today = new Date();
      if(date!=null)
       return date>today
      else
       return true
   }
  return
  {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link : function(scope,element,attrs,ctrl)
    {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel,function(newValue,oldValue))
        {
            if(newValue!=oldValue)
            {
                var check_date=maxDate(newValue)
                ctrl.setValidity('maxdatevalidator',check_date) ;             
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The inputs are missing `ng-model` directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put an ng-show on the ul showing only when the checkbox is true.
First you'll need an ng-model for the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="mainControl.reportUpdates()" ng-model="reportUpdates">
```

Then you can add then ng-show to the ul:

```
<ul messages="mainform['date'+$index].$error" ng-show="reportUpdates">
```